# target_function() missing 1 required positional argument 'capacity':

Tags: python, routes, genetic-algorithm

Capacity is called via the main python file and is embedded within a function that determines whether the vehicle capacity is exceeded for a certain subroute defined in the Genetic algorithm. I cannot figure out why python provides the error for a missing required positional argument as capacity should be put into the parameter max_capacity

## GA-VRP-co2 Function

```
def genetic_algorithm_vrp(coordinates, distance_matrix, parameters, co2_per_km, capacity, population_size = 5, vehicle_types = 9, n_depots = 1, route = 'closed', model = 'vrp'
,fleet_size = [], mutation_rate = 0.1, elite = 0, generations = 50, penalty_value = 1000, graph = True):  

start           = tm.time()
count           = 0
solution_report = ['None']
max_capacity = copy.deepcopy(capacity)

for i in range(0, n_depots):
  parameters[i, 0] = 0  
population       = initial_population(coordinates, distance_matrix, population_size = 
population_size, vehicle_types = vehicle_types, n_depots = n_depots, model = model)
co2, population = target_function(population, distance_matrix, parameters, co2_per_km, max_capacity, penalty_value = penalty_value, route = route, fleet_size = fleet_size)   
fitness          = fitness_function_co2(co2, population_size) 
co2, population = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(co2, population))))
elite_ind        = elite_distance(population[0], distance_matrix, route = route)
solution         = copy.deepcopy(population[0])
print('Generation = ', count, ' Distance = ', elite_ind, ' f(x) = ', round(co2[0][0],2)) 
while (count <= generations-1): 
    offspring        = breeding(co2, population, fitness, distance_matrix, n_depots, elite, max_capacity, co2_per_km, penalty_value, parameters, route, vehicle_types, fleet_size)   
    offspring        = mutation(offspring, mutation_rate = mutation_rate, elite = elite)
    co2, population = target_function(offspring, distance_matrix, parameters, co2_per_km, max_capacity, penalty_value, route = route, fleet_size = fleet_size)
    fitness          = fitness_function_co2(co2, population_size)  
    co2, population = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(co2, population)))) 
    elite_ind        = elite_distance(population[0], distance_matrix, route = route)
    solution         = copy.deepcopy(population[0])
    count            = count + 1  
    print('Generation = ', count, ' Distance = ', elite_ind, ' f(x) = ', round(co2[0][0],2))

    if (graph == True):
    plot_tour_coordinates(coordinates, solution, n_depots = n_depots, route = route)
    solution_report = show_report(solution, distance_matrix, parameters, co2_per_km, route = route)
 end = tm.time()
 print('Algorithm Time: ', round((end - start),2), ' seconds')  
 print('route sequence', route)   
 return solution_report, solution
```

Comment: Which line in the code does the error happened?

Comment: Hi Ferdy, thanks for responding. I have been able to solve the issue.

Comment: Alright that is good.